"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 3" error when reading GeoJSON into GeoDataFrame with non UTF-8 encoding
Is it currently possible to read a simple GeoJSON file which has non-utf8 encoding for certain field names and/or field values in GeoPandas v 0.14.2? Here's an example:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "SP07___SP22_BACHES_A_EAUX",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 1, "Id": 0, "N": 5, "Nom": "SP09", "Fon´┐¢ier": " ", "Phase": "Phase 1", "Date_": "15/06/23", "retenue": "", "PROJET_EN_COURS": "EXISTANTE" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 254448.773599997162819, 119554.822999998927116 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 16, "Id": 0, "N": 3, "Nom": "SP07", "Fon´┐¢ier": " ", "Phase": "Phase 1", "Date_": "15/06/23", "retenue": "", "PROJET_EN_COURS": "EXISTANTE" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 254424.692699998617172, 121807.375199999660254 ] } }
]
}

The characters are recognized by Notepad++ and appear as follows:

When I try to read the above file with gpd.read_file("test.geojson") I get an error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 3: invalid continuation byte

Specifying the optional argument encoding="utf-8" or encoding="latin1" doesn't seem to help. Is this currently supported?

Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte

How is this supposed to look like when it is correct?

@Bera Its a c cedilla

And should it look like Fonçier?

The (Geo)JSON standard is quite strict in the encodings that are supported: only UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 (JSON standard). Most JSON parsers also limit support to these encodings, including the libraries used by Geopandas to read/write files.
But, as it is a text format, this is easy to solve: you can let Python convert from latin to UTF-8. When you open a text file with an encoding specified, python will by default convert the data to a UTF-8 string when read. Hence, if you pass this opened file to geopandas.read_file, it will read the data as being in UTF-8.
Sample script:
import geopandas as gpd

path = r"C:\Temp\geojson_latin\latin.geojson"
with open(path, 'r', encoding='latin') as file:
    gdf = gpd.read_file(file)

print(gdf.columns)

Output:
Index(['OBJECTID', 'Id', 'N', 'Nom', 'Fonçier', 'Phase', 'Date_', 'retenue',
       'PROJET_EN_COURS', 'geometry'],
      dtype='object')

